# QPlainTextEdit memory leak

Tags: memory-management, memory-leaks, g++, qwidget, qplaintextedit

I wrote a simple app with Qt 5.9.6, I ran that and wondered the used memory is **growing**.
After tracing/debugging my application, I realized something about ***QPlainTextEdit*** !!!

The memory leak was for a qplaintextedit as a scratchpad in my app, but after every use of that, I used the **clear()** function to blank it for next use.

But the used memory by that scratchpad woudn't be released!

### I decided to test it

I opened a new project, containing a **QPlainTextEdit** & a **QPushButton**(to use clear() function).

- After run, the used memory was `9.7MiB`
- Entered some long text to QPlainTextEdit, the used memory was `52MiB`
- Pressed the QPushButton(clear() the QPlainTextEdit), **the expected  used memory is `9.7MiB`, but it was `52MiB`.**

I tried **delete**, **static allocation**, **dynamic allocation**..., many ways to manage that, but no different!

I found something in [here](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/33572-QTextEdit-memory-leak-is-this-a-bug?p=192560#post192560), but it couldn't solve the problem.

Is this a bug in QPlainTextEdit or I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How did you measure the memory usage of the program ? You can't rely on standard system tools for that purpose because system optimizations can keep memory reserved for a potential next use, in other words, memory is not necessarily returned back to the system immediately.

Comment: @Fareanor I've traced memory with Heaptrack.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is Qt's defection.

You can run the Appliction.exe  example of Qt , it also has the same problem.

Comment: Not sure it's a defect, see [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53378583/qplaintextedit-memory-leak#comment133750010_53378583) about it.